# How to receive data from Provider inside another provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

i'm wondering how to receive data from a Provider class called `<Data>` inside my provider class `Player` below. As you can see here in my example I have a play function which needs data and awaits a String. The data is inside a provider String called `Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false).url;`

I'm getting error because of the context. There is no context and my way of implementing `Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false).url;` is wrong. So my question: how to implement `Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false).url;` the correct way? How to receive this data? Thank you for your help!

```
class Player with ChangeNotifier {

  String path;
  final url = Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false).url;

  void setPlayList(videosList) {
    url = path;
  }

  Future play() async {
   //my function
   await player.play(path);

  playerState = PlayerState.playing;
   notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` :

```dart
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Data, Player>(
          create: (_) => Player(),
          update: (_, data, player) => player..update(data),
        )
```

in your `Player` class:

```dart
class Player with ChangeNotifier {

  String path;
  String _url;

  void update(Data data) {
    _url = data.url;
  }

...

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, can you show me an example on my above code? greetings

Comment: Do you want only receive  ```url``` from ```Data``` class or modify this value from ```Player``` class?

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you show me both ways, so I can learn from it. :) But for the example I just need to receive `url` from `Data` class.